# Searching with special character on google play application

Tags: android, google-play, symbols

My application is named with a special character "ë" that exists in my language. But usually people write "ë" as "e" and in that case application is not found, my application name contains only one special character. How I can deal with it? Is there any way? I do not want to name it without "ë" because it is wrong.

Comment: I believe Google understands characters without accents also.

Comment: What do you mean? I included also without "ë" on description and it is showed at description live but when I search without "ë" it does not show. I am afraid that all people will search without "ë" because they do not use it much.

Comment: Then what's the best solution for this? @edoniti I am hanged with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835775/given-mixed-accented-and-normal-characters-in-string-not-working-in-java-when-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the name without special characters on the description, I added at the end, after some hours now it works great.