# Given mixed accented and normal characters in string not working in java when searching

Tags: java, android, regex

```
String text = "Cámélan discovered ônte red aleŕt \n Como se extingue la deuda";
```

If I give the input Ca, it should highlight from the given string Cá but it's not highlighting.

Below is what I tried.

```
 Pattern mPattern; 
  String filterTerm; //this is the input which I give from input filter. Say for eg: Ca
   String regex = createFilterRegex(filterTerm);
        mPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

 private String createFilterRegex(String filterTerm) {
        filterTerm = Normalizer.normalize(filterTerm, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
       filterTerm = filterTerm.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");
        return filterTerm;
    }

public Pattern getPattern() {
        return mPattern;
    }
```

In another class,

```
private SpannableStringBuilder createHighlightedString(String nodeText, int highlightColor) { //nodeText is the entire list displaying. 
        SpannableStringBuilder returnValue = new SpannableStringBuilder(nodeText);
        String lowercaseNodeText = nodeText;
        Matcher matcher = mFilter.getPattern().matcher((createFilterRegex(lowercaseNodeText)));
        while (matcher.find()) {
            returnValue.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(highlightColor), matcher.start(0),
                    matcher.end(0), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

viewHolder.mTextView.setText(createHighlightedString((node.getText()), mHighlightColor));

But what I am getting the output as,

If I type single alphabet o alone, it's highlighting but if I pass more than two alphabets say for eg: Ca, it's not highlighting and displaying. I couldn't figure out what mistake I am doing.

But if you look WhatsApp. it has been achieved.

I typed Co,  it's recognizing and highlighting accented characters in the sentence.

[image]

Comment: Did you try my solution @Star ?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Yes. But still not working.

Comment: what is the problem @Star ?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit issue is When i search as Ca in content, it's not accepting this Cá. Only when I search Cá it's accepting.

Comment: Did you use both of the codes I gave in the answer to make the string ignore accented characters?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I tried too but still facing after removing accented characters in search.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182244/discussion-between-star-and-pradyuman-dixit).

Comment: I doubt this can be done, but if you get these `\p{Block=Latin_1_Supplement}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_A}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_Additional}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_B}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_C}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_D}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_E}` and convert them into basic Latin with the combining code, all you have to do is inject `[\x{300}-\x{36F}]?` after all input Latin alpha characters.

Comment: Hello @sln Thanks. can you please answer and frame it. It it works, let me accept and close it.

Comment: Ok, I posted something that might help.

Answer (score 2):

As you said,

String text = "Cámélan discovered ônte red aleŕt \n Como se extingue la deuda";

So whenever you give first input, receive that first character and compare.

Eg: If you give Ca,  then

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(substring)) { //this is the search text
substring=substring.substring(0,1); //now you get C alone.
```

}

So whatever you type it displays by filtering the first character. Now

```
 SpannableString builder = higlightString((yourContent.getText()), mHighlightColor);
    viewHolder.mTextView.setText(builder);




private SpannableString higlightString(String entireContent, int highlightColor) {
            SpannableString returnValue = new SpannableString(entireContent);

            String lowercaseNodeText = entireContent;
        try {
            Matcher matcher = mFilter.getPattern().matcher(((diacritical(lowercaseNodeText.toLowerCase()))));
            while (matcher.find()) {
                returnValue.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(highlightColor), matcher.start(0),
                        matcher.end(0), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return returnValue;

    }



 private String diacritical(String original) {
       String removed=null;
           String decomposed = Normalizer.normalize(original, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
           removed = decomposed.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
       return removed;
   }
```

Test case:

When you give input Ca, it goes to the entire text by displaying all the C content get all the datas and filter out by normalising the content and it matches with accented characters too and display by higlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You already got:

```
private String convertToBasicLatin(String text) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{M}", "").replaceAll("\\R", "\n");
}
```

In order to have **one** unaccented basic latin char match **one** Unicode code point of an accented letter,
one should normalize the to the *composed* form:

```
private String convertToComposedCodePoints(String text) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFC).replaceAll("\\R", "\n");
}
```

In general one might make the assumption that the Unicode code point is 1 char long too.

- The search key uses convertToBasicLatin(sought)
- The text view's content uses convertToComposedCodePoints(content)
- The text content for matching uses convertToBasicLatin(content)

Now the matcher's index positions of `start` and `end` are correct.
I normalized explicitly line endings (regex `\R`) like `\r\n` or `\u0085` to a single `\n`.
One cannot normalize to lowercase/uppercase, as the number of chars might vary:
German lowercase `ß` corresponds with uppercase `SS`.

```
String sought = ...;
String content = ...;

sought = convertToBasicLatin(sought);
String latinContent = convertToBasicLatin(content);
String composedContent = convertToComposedUnicode(content);

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sought, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
        | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS
        | Pattern.UNIX_LINES)
    .matcher(latinContent);
while (m.find()) {
    ... // One can apply `m.start()` and `m.end()` to composedContent of the view too.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joop Eggen. May I know why I am not able to use Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS. If I use this, I am getting crash that [Android] Unsupprted Flag 256 for Pattern.java

Comment: Drop that flag, different java implementations. Good for others to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java programmer, so just some basic raw regex solution here.

If you can *Normalize* the string with it's *decomposition* form
assume it's this

`String sSourceTargetDecom = Normalizer.normalize(sourcetarget, Normalizer.Form.NFD);`,

that should turn something like `0000C1 Á LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE`
into two characters `A` and `000301 ́  COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`.

You can get most combining characters from blocks using

```
[\p{Block=Combining_Diacritical_Marks}\p{Block=Combining_Diacritical_Marks_Extended}\p{Block=Combining_Diacritical_Marks_For_Symbols}\p{Block=Combining_Diacritical_Marks_Supplement}\p{Block=Combining_Half_Marks}]
```

which has a hex range of

```
[\x{300}-\x{36f}\x{1ab0}-\x{1aff}\x{1dc0}-\x{1dff}\x{20d0}-\x{20ff}\x{fe20}-\x{fe2f}]
```

It turns out that most of the combining marks relative to basic Latin that can be
decomposed are in the `[\x{300}-\x{36f}]` range.

You can decompose *both* the source target and the input search string.

---

Then create a regex from the input search string.
*Inject* `[\x{300}-\x{36f}]?`  after each basic Latin letter.

```
String regex = sSearch.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])[\\x{300}-\\x{36f}]?", "\\1[\\x{300}-\\x{36f}]?");
```

(not sure what Java uses for codepoint character notation in their regex, possibly needs to be `\u{DD}`

Then use the regex on the *sSourceTargetDecom* string, it will match the basic latin as a stand alone, and/or with an optional combining code.